# Rubik's Cube rotation in Python

Tags: python

I've got a representation of a Rubik's Cube and I'm trying to add rotation methods. I've been banging my head against this for more than a day, and I just can't find the bug in my code.

I've got a Box class which has string attributes for each of its six faces. I fill a 3X3X3 array with Boxes in the Cube class (including a redundant Box at the center of the Cube, but this code is still unoptimized). Then I assign the correct colors to the boxes, with values of 'none' if that face isn't visible from outside the Cube.

Up until here, it works perfectly, but when I added the first rotation method, rot_front(), it spits out a weird result.

I've added debug methods if you wanna try it out. Here's my code:

```
class Box:
    def __init__(self):
        self.top = 'none'
        self.bottom = 'none'
        self.right = 'none'
        self.left = 'none'
        self.front = 'none'
        self.back = 'none'

class Cube:
    def __init__(self):
        self.boxes = [[[Box() for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)] for i in range(3)]

        for z in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                for x in range(3):
                    if z == 0:
                        self.boxes[z][y][x].front = 'white'
                    if z == 2:
                        self.boxes[z][y][x].back = 'yellow'

                    if y == 0:
                        self.boxes[z][y][x].top = 'red'
                    if y == 2:
                        self.boxes[z][y][x].bottom = 'orange'

                    if x == 0:
                        self.boxes[z][y][x].left = 'blue'
                    if x == 2:
                        self.boxes[z][y][x].right = 'green'

    def print_front(self):
        z = 0
        for y in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                print(cube.boxes[z][y][x].front, end=" ")
            print("")

    def print_back(self):
        z = 2
        for y in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                print(cube.boxes[z][y][x].back, end=" ")
            print("")

    def print_top(self):
        y = 0
        for z in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                print(cube.boxes[z][y][x].top, end=" ")
            print("")

    def print_bottom(self):
        y = 2
        for z in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                print(cube.boxes[z][y][x].bottom, end=" ")
            print("")

    def print_left(self):
        x = 0
        for z in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                print(cube.boxes[z][y][x].left, end=" ")
            print("")

    def print_right(self):
        x = 2
        for z in range(3):
            for y in range(3):
                print(cube.boxes[z][y][x].right, end=" ")
            print("")

    def rot_front(self):
        front_face = self.boxes[0]
        for y in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                target = front_face[2-x][y]

                self.boxes[0][y][x].top = target.left
                self.boxes[0][y][x].right = target.top
                self.boxes[0][y][x].bottom = target.right
                self.boxes[0][y][x].left = target.bottom



cube = Cube()
cube.rot_front()


print("FRONT")
cube.print_front()
print("BACK")
cube.print_back()

print("TOP")
cube.print_top()
print("BOTTOM")
cube.print_bottom()

print("LEFT")
cube.print_left()
print("RIGHT")
cube.print_right()
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: What did you find out when you used your debug methods?

Comment: maybe making different classes based on whether the 'box' is the central one, it's on edge or on a cornel, considering they behave differently.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest method is to make a deepcopy of `self.boxes` and change it and then replace `self.boxes` at the end of the rotation:

```py
import copy

class Cube:
    # other methods stay the same
    def rot_front(self):
        front_face = self.boxes[0]
        new_state = copy.deepcopy(self.boxes)
        for y in range(3):
            for x in range(3):
                target = front_face[2-x][y]

                new_state[0][y][x].top = target.left
                new_state[0][y][x].right = target.top
                new_state[0][y][x].bottom = target.right
                new_state[0][y][x].left = target.bottom
        self.boxes = new_state
```

The mistake you made is a little bit hard to explain because I'm not a native english speaker, bit I'll try:

You are moving the information from one box to another in the loop. But in some cases the information in `target` contains information which already was moved and you move it again.

Comment: I debugged the code and agree. If you printout your 'targets' you get more than 3 for some colors which indicate that the values are being moved more than once. Therefore a copy should solve the issue preserving the colors that are being moved so that you can move them safely.